# how to access SessionMode in WCF

Tags: wcf

.NET framework 4.0
How do you programatically access SessionMode in WCF on the client side?
How do you programatically access SessionMode in WCF on the server side?

Comment: On the client side? I would say not at all - on the server side you just check the attribute...

Comment: What's your goal? Are you trying to make a decision at run time or design time?

Comment: it has not been specified and i want to confirm the value (check the default)

Comment: I should have mentioned in my last comment that I want to check the value at run time.

Answer (score 0):

found answer here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/bf1ecbec-4eda-4dc5-ba26-c7ad43247b93

ServerSide

```
System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IService1)).SessionMode.ToString()
```

ClientSide

```
 System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ServiceReference1.IService1)).SessionMode
```